# How to Send multiple content-type Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to send multiple content type on a single ajax request. How do i do it with the following ajax request?

I want to add html with some data and some data needs to set somewhere else.

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "{{url('searchByRange')}}",
      dataType: 'html',
      data: 
        { 
          first_date : first_date, 
          second_date : second_date,  
          id :id                     
        },

        success: function(html) // How do i set html and other content type here?
        {
          totalVisitors = ; // I want to set $visitors here...
          $(".date-range").html(html);
        } ,
        error: function(error) 
        { 
         // console.log(error);
        }           
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way to send a collection of data over HTTP is to use JSON.

Just have the server respond with a JSON text. You could include an object or array with properties containing strings of HTML.

```
{
    "totalVisitors": "<p>foo bar<\/p>",
    "somethingElse": "<p>foo bar<\/p>"
}
```

Make sure your server-side code generates a `Content-Type: application/json` response header and not `Content-Type: text/html`.

Obviously you would need to change `dataType: 'html'` to `dataType: 'json'`